# Select some default values if no row is found in a union

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do something like this, where there is no existing row with ID=2

```
SELECT 
     coalesce( ID, 1 ) as ID 
     , coalesce( someVal, 0 ) as someVal
     FROM tablename WHERE ID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
     coalesce( ID, 2 ) as ID 
     , coalesce( someVal, 0 ) as someVal
     FROM tablename WHERE ID = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 
     coalesce( ID, 3 ) as ID 
     , coalesce( someVal, 0 ) as someVal
     FROM tablename WHERE ID = 3
```

What I get is

```
ID   |    someVal
1    |    500.23
3    |    492.01
```

What I want is

```
ID   |    someVal
1    |    500.23
2    |    0
3    |    492.01
```

How can I make this return a row with some default values if there's no record for the corresponding ID?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to select both columns in two different select

```
 SELECT ISNULL((SELECT isnull( ID, 2 ) FROM #tablename WHERE ID = 2),2) ,
 ISNULL((SELECT isnull( someval, 2 ) FROM #tablename WHERE ID = 2),0)
```

Code:

```
create table #tablename (id int ,someval int)

insert into  #tablename values (1,500)

insert into  #tablename values (3,492.23)

 SELECT ISNULL((SELECT isnull( ID, 1 ) FROM #tablename WHERE ID = 1),2) ,
 ISNULL((SELECT isnull( someval, 0 ) FROM #tablename WHERE ID = 1),0)
 union all
 SELECT ISNULL((SELECT isnull( ID, 2 ) FROM #tablename WHERE ID = 2),2) ,
 ISNULL((SELECT isnull( someval, 0 ) FROM #tablename WHERE ID = 2),0)
 union all
 SELECT ISNULL((SELECT isnull( ID, 3 ) FROM #tablename WHERE ID = 3),2) ,
 ISNULL((SELECT isnull( someval, 0 ) FROM #tablename WHERE ID = 3),0)
```

Comment: Is there no way to do `select when exists`? This looks like it would be resource-heavy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have numbers table with values for ID and use LEFT JOIN with original table as given below. the numbers table can be a temporary table also, based on your need.

```
DECLARE @tbl table(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeVal INT) 
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(1)  
,(2)
,(3); 

DECLARE @numtbl TABLE(ID INT);
INSERT INTO @numtbl VALUES
(1)  
,(2)
,(3)
,(4) -- not present in original table
,(5); --not present in original table

SELECT (t.ID) as id, COALESCE(t1.SomeVal,0)  as someval
FROM
@numtbl AS t 
LEFT JOIN @tbl AS t1
ON t.ID = t1.ID 
WHERE t.ID = 5 -- ID is not present in original table
```